# display alertview while deleting data in plist

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I want to delete data in UITableView using plist and i want to put alertview when delete button is pressed.  I want to mention that i have used edit button to delete the data from tableview. code of edit button is as follows: for your information.

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=self.editButtonItem;
```

Plz help me solve this problem.

thanx in advance.

Comment: do you wnat code for diplaying alert view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function write :

```
     UIAlertView    *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"" message: @"" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
alertView.tag = 1;
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
```

On alert "OK" button pressed

```
  - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
        { 
    if(buttonIndex==0)
        {
    if (alertView.tag == 1)
        {
    //Do your code
    }
   }
 }
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

on you button action write:-

```
-(IBAction)btnPressed
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
}
```